# How many ways "ARRANGE" can be arranged?

Tags: reference-request

In how many ways can the letter of the word "ARRANGE" be arranged in which two Rs and two As come together?

Comment: Your [prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961883/how-many-words-can-be-formed-by-taking-three-letters-from-the-letters-of-the-wor) was closed because you did not include any of your efforts.   What have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: It is a Permutation with repetitions

Answer (score 5):

We have to arrange all the letters of word ***ARRANGE*** such that AA and RR come together.

So, Put both **A's** and **R's** together,
i.e. consider **AA** and **RR** as single entities.

> ***n*** items can be arranged in n! ways:
>   Proof:
>   $1^{st}$ item has n options, $2^{nd}$ item has (n-1) options,....$n^{th}$ item has 1 option.
>    So, total ways are:$$n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\cdot\cdot\cdot1$$ i.e. n! ways.

You have ***AA,RR,N,G,E*** i.e. **5** entities to be arranged.
You can arrange **5** items amongst themselves in **5!** ways.

So, final answer is **5!=120** ways.

Comment: But AA and RR are not always next to each other so how can you treat them like single entries?

Comment: I think it is $$\frac{7!}{2!\cdot 2!}=1260$$

Comment: Whats wrong to consider AA and RR as a single entity? That gives 5!

Comment: I misread the post.

Comment: @omega your approach is correct (+1). In permutations with repetition are  allowed the (numerous) cases where A,A or R,R are not neighbours.